# How to create contact in android

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is I want to create one contact with image, and beside contact image I want to show name of contact.

Here below is my code: Here also I m able to create contact, but I am not able to get exact output.

Code:

```
<LinearLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<QuickContactBadge

    android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="CheckedTextView" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

My out put:

[image]

Required out put:

[image]

Please anybody suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick contact badge needs to be fed some data.  The circular head+smile image is what you get if you haven't applied any data.  You should get a Uri and assign that to the badge.

Here is a nice tutorial by Shane Conder & Lauren Darcey:  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_contact-badge/

Here is code snippet from the tutorial, showing how to populate the badge:

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();  
        FrameLayout badgeLargeHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.badge_holder_large);  
        QuickContactBadge badgeLarge = new QuickContactBadge(this);  
        badgeLarge.assignContactUri(contactUri);  
        badgeLarge.setMode(ContactsContract.QuickContact.MODE_LARGE);  
        badgeLarge.setImageResource(R.drawable.droid_small);  
        badgeLargeHolder.addView(badgeLarge);
```